# Using filename to assign variables in matlab

Tags: matlab

This may be a simple question, but a matlab noob here and I can't find something similar in searching.

I have a bunch of filenames like this that I'm looping through: goes12.2009.242.201515.BAND_01.nc

I want to assign the 8-11th character (ie 2009) as the year, the 13-15th (ie 242) as the day, the 17-18th (ie 20) as the hour, the 19-20th (ie 15) as the min and the 21-22 (ie 15) as the second.

I believe this can be done somewhat simply?
Thanks so much in advance for any insight!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, it can be done
u just need to transform the string (character) into number

```
filename=goes12.2009.242.201515.BAND_01.nc;
yr=str2double(filename(8:11));
doy=str2double(filename(13:15));
hr=str2double(filename(17:18));
min=str2double(filename(19:20));
sec=str2double(filename(21:22));
```

and good luck with nc data

Comment: Thanks so much @foxkingdom - This worked perfectly!! I had an idea of using string into number but didn't know how to execute. Appreciate the help!